# PAQ compression

Tags: algorithm, compression

I've been struggling to understand the PAQ algorithm completely. Wikipedia seems convoluted enough. Even though i'm taking a course in neural networks and artificial intelligence at the moment, there are some terms and assertions that are hard to digest, especially the [arithmetic coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAQ#Arithmetic_coding) part of the algorithm.

i could find [another link](http://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/compression/paq.html) but that's filled with PAQ's versions and their respective benchmarks.

Can someone please suggest a good page(text,video, audio, anything will do!) which offers a lucid explanation.

Comment: Check whether this helps: http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq1.pdf It's one of the reference article on the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

A simple explanation for context mixing and partial prediction match is when you feed the compression with a specific model. For example the probability of some letters is higher then others and that is shared with other languages too. A different model cause an entropy compression to compress a tad better. A paq compression uses this to choose the best available model and compression. When you have problems to understand arithmetic compressions look for a range compression basically it's the same but it's easier to understand: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_encoding#section_1.